# How to Optimize a loop "For" in Django

Tags: python, json, django, for-loop, django-models

I want to optimize this functions, because they take too long, each of them bring specific atributes, if you can help me. I think there's maybe a way to call the atributes in the function.
The functions are made with python and Django.

This is what i've done so far.

Definition of the functions.

```
cand_seleccionados = ListaFinal.objects.filter(interesado__id_oferta=efectiva.oferta.id)

seleccionados_ids = cand_seleccionados.values_list("interesado_id", flat=True)

cand_postulados = Postulados.objects.filter(
    interesado__id_oferta=efectiva.oferta.id
).exclude(interesado_id__in=seleccionados_ids)

postulados_ids = cand_postulados.values_list("interesado_id", flat=True)

cand_entrevistados = Entrevistados.objects.filter(
    interesado__id_oferta=efectiva.oferta.id
).exclude(interesado_id__in=postulados_ids)
```

This is the loop for cand_Postulados, the others are the same so i thought it wouldnt be necesary to put more

```
for p in cand_postulados:

    postulado = dict()

    telefono = Perfil.objects.values_list("telefono", flat=True).get(
        user_id=p.interesado.candidato.id
    )

    postulado["id"] = p.interesado.candidato.id
    postulado["nombre"] = p.interesado.candidato.first_name
    postulado["email"] = p.interesado.candidato.email
    postulado["teléfono"] = telefono

    if p.interesado.id_oferta.pais is None:
        postulado["pais"] = "Sin pais registrado"
    else:
        postulado["pais"] = p.interesado.id_oferta.pais.nombre

    postulado["nombre_reclutador"] = p.interesado.id_reclutador.first_name
    postulado["id_reclutador"] = p.interesado.id_reclutador.id

    postulados.append(postulado)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your loop correctly, this should do everything in a single query. (You may need to adjust some of the [`__` spanning lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) if I read things incorrectly. In particular, I don't necessarily know the reverse name of your `Perfil` to `user` relationship.)

```
cand_postulados = (
    Postulados.objects
    .filter(interesado__id_oferta=efectiva.oferta.id)
    .exclude(interesado_id__in=seleccionados_ids)
)
postulados = list(cand_postulados.values(
    teléfono="interesado__candidato__telefono",
    nombre="interesado__candidato__first_name",
    email="interesado__candidato__email",
    pais="interesado__id_oferta__pais__nombre",
    nombre_reclutador="interesado__id_reclutador__first_name",
    id_reclutador="interesado__id_reclutador__id",
))
for datum in postulados:
    if not datum.get("pais"):
        datum["pais"] = "Sin pais registrado"
```